# Bind the Selected option text To Input box

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im new to react, Im acheiving to search the text,which will post to the api, and the results will be displayed as options in  box,for which im using twitter bootstrap just the className's to match with REACT.I want to make the make the `option's` value to be bind to the input text box above, if i select the option. How to achieve this using useRef and at the same time ,the select box should close if the option is selected.The HandleCHange for the input box triggers the api call for every keystrole

Below is the code for the select box.

```
 <input
        className='form-control'
        placeholder='Search Drug...'
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
<select class='custom-select' size={drugList.drugs?.length> 0 ? '10' : ''} onChange={handleSelectChange}>
        
        {drugList.drugs?.length > 0 &&
          drugList.drugs.map((each,index) => {
            return (
              <option key={index} value={`${each.drug}`}>
                {each.drug}
              </option>
            )
          })}
     
      </select>
```

Here i want the selected value to be bind to the input box.It will be great if you give the sample code or snippet.

[image]
Please refer the image above.Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

*I want to make the make the option's value to be bind to the input text box above*
---> use component state to store the selected value from the  options  dropdown
*at the same time ,the select box should close if the option is selected.*
----> hide/display select options based on input box focus by toggling component state.

[created a sandbox for your app, please check](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-wind-wvmoi?file=/src/App.js:0-1505)

Comment: @Aashiqahmed , I am glad that I could help, you can accept the answer if you think it helped: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this like this.

```
handleSelectChange = (event) =>{
 this.setState({selectvalue:event.target.value});
}
handleChange= (event) =>{
  this.setState({selectvalue:event.target.value});
   ---- and your code here---
} 

<input
    className='form-control'
    placeholder='Search Drug...'
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    value={this.state.selectvalue}
/>
<select class='custom-select' size={drugList.drugs?.length> 0 ? '10' : ''} onChange={this.handleSelectChange}>            
        {drugList.drugs?.length > 0 &&
          drugList.drugs.map((each,index) => {
            return (
              <option key={index} value={`${each.drug}`}>
                {each.drug}
              </option>
            )
          })}             
</select>
```

Comment: I can't type in the input box.

Comment: The handleChange in the input box,triggers api call for every key stroke

Comment: I cant type in the input box, I want to type in Both in Input box and on after select the option should be in the input box